# Android Spinner setAdapter () on a null object reference exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-widget, android-spinner, android-dialog

My goal is add items to spinner dynamically, I want to do it in dialog (not an activity class) but I get an exception like this `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference`

`DisKapiList` is my list which contains items for adding to spinner.

Here is my code;

```
spBBKapiNo = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(UIUtils.getResourceId(wrapper.getmActiviy(), "spBBKapiNo", "id"));

disKapList = yapi.getNumaratajList();
    List <SpinnerObject> lables = getAllLabels();
    ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(wrapper.getmActiviy(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(UIUtils.getResourceId(wrapper.getmActiviy(), "spBBKapiNo", "id"));
    spBBKapiNo.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and `getAllLabels()` method is;

```
public List <SpinnerObject> getAllLabels(){
    List < SpinnerObject > labels = new ArrayList < SpinnerObject > ();

    for (Numarataj object : disKapList) {
        labels.add ( new SpinnerObject ( object.getId() , object.getKapiNo() ));
    }

    return labels;
}
```

Spinner field in my layout;

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spBBKapiNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/empty_array"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
```

Edit ;

Now I can see my SpinnerList on dilaog but when I clilcked spinner to see other options , program shut down with Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0f0069 type #0x12 is not valid.

Comment: Please post your layout code and spBBKapiNo initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved !

```
List <SpinnerObject> lables = getAllLabels();
        ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(wrapper.getmActiviy(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spBBKapiNo.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```